# Applying regexp and finding the highest number in a list

Tags: python-2.7

I have got a list of different names. I have a script that prints out the names from the list.

```
req=urllib2.Request('http://some.api.com/')
req.add_header('AUTHORIZATION', 'Token token=hash')
response = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
json_content = json.loads(response)
for name in json_content:
   print name['name']
```

Output:

```
Thomas001
Thomas002
Alice001
Ben001
Thomas120
```

I need to find the max number that comes with the name Thomas. Is there a simple way to to apply regexp for all the elements that contain "Thomas" and then apply max(list) to them? The only way that I have came up with is to go through each element in the list, match regexp for Thomas, then strip the letters and put the remaining numbers to a new list, but this seems pretty bulky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need regular expressions, and you don't need sorting. As you said, `max()` is fine. To be safe in case the list contains names like "Thomasson123", you can use:

```
names = ((x['name'][:6], x['name'][6:]) for x in json_content)
max(int(b) for a, b in names if a == 'Thomas' and b.isdigit())
```

The first assignment creates a generator expression, so there will be only one pass over the sequence to find the maximum.

Comment: Cheers, i think i will work my way out with this. Though if i apply your solution, it prints me out "9" even though the highest number that starts with "Thomas" is way over 100.

Comment: @SarunasUrbelis I assumed the numbers were zero-filled. Casting string to int before taking maximum will fix it, see updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to go for regex. Just store the results in a list and then apply `sorted` function on that.

```
>>> l = ['Thomas001',
'homas002',
'Alice001',
'Ben001',
'Thomas120']
>>> [i for i in sorted(l) if i.startswith('Thomas')][-1]
'Thomas120'
```